# HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable in spring MVC Rest Service

Tags: java, spring, rest

Here is my code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report/download", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/vnd.ms-excel")
    public Response getReportFile(@QueryParam("reportid") Long reportId)
    {
        System.out.println("Param"+reportId);
        Long n=(long) 10;
        String json=reportService.getReportFile(n);
        File file = new File("D:\\Agent Information.xls");  
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);  
        response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Sample.xls");  
        return response.build();  
    }
```

i am getting the below Error in java console: Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: could you please provide more logs ? ideally stacktrace from application after making call to the endpoint

Comment: AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.logException:186 -> Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation ...   and whiile hit in browser i am getting "The target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request, and the server is unwilling to supply a default representation."

Comment: Please suggest to resolve this

Comment: Your error says thats there is not proper converter for your response.What is that "Response" class you used, is it part of spring MVC at all i doubt it's not, try using ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> as response and send the file as stream.

Comment: I have used Jaxrs response class but i am getting this response. even tried with simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Your webservice is saying that the response type it is returning is not provided in the `Accept HTTP header` in your Client request.

So while making HTTP Request you have to add 'Accept Headers' . If it's `JSON` request then you will add `'Accept : application/json'`. Similarly for your current example it will be

```
'Accept: text/plain'
'Accept-Charset: utf-8'
```

Find all [accept headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) here. And follow this steps to resolve

1) Find out the `response (content type)` returned by web service.

2) Provide this (content type) in your request Accept header.

Comment: Thanks for you reply... i have published the web service and i am testing in local... so i have given all the header exactly but still facing the same issue :( :(

Comment: I guess your produces is creating a issue here.  Try changing produces="application/vnd.ms-excel" to produces = "application/json" or remove it completely. You can add response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); instead of it before your statement  - response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Sample.xls");